# Ошибка про несоответствие типа передаваемого параметра: int cannot be converted to BigInteger

Tags: java, рекурсия

Задача о зернах на шахматном поле рекурсией. Код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        go(1, 1);
    }

    static void go(int i, BigInteger count) {
        count *= 2;
        if (i >= 64) return;
        go(i + 1, count);
    }
}
```

Компилятор жалуется на несоответствие типа передаваемого параметра:

```
int cannot be converted to BigInteger  
        go(1, 1);


bad operand types for binary operator '*'
        count *= 2;
```

в чем дело?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878192/converting-from-integer-to-biginteger

Comment: go(1, BigInteger.valueOf(1)); && count = count.multiply( BigInteger.valueOf(2))

Answer (score 1):

```
count = count.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
```